# Fill Key Across Rows Instead of Down Columns

Tags: gnuplot

I currently position my key with:

```
set key outside bottom horizontal
```

I have 6 items in the key, coming from two `plot for...` commands (3 each). The size of my plot results in a key that is 2 rows x 3 columns. I'd like to fill my key across rows instead of down columns so that the nth item from each plot command is aligned vertically:

Current:

```
135
246
```

Desired:

```
123
456
```

I can't find any options for this in `help set key`. Is this possible without changing my plotting commands?

Comment: I suspect not, sorry. You can try tricks with dummy plots, but the easiest way is probably to manually adjust the ordering of plot commands and line styles.

Answer (score 0):

In the multiplot environment for placing multiple graphs you have the option `rowsfirst` and `columnsfirst` (check `help multiplot`).
Although, for the key entries you have the options `vertical` and `horizontal` (check `help key`). And as you hoped that `horizontal` would solve your problem, I also would have expected that `horizontal` together with the option `maxcols 3` would do what you're requesting. But it doesn't. Hence, you need a workaround.

You don't specify where you get your key entries from. From the columheader or from some string created with some index? So, in the example below I assumed a key is created from your two loop indices.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### change order in legend/key
reset

M = 2   # rows
N = 3   # columns
myTitles = ''
set key noautotitle maxrows M
set offsets 0,0,0.5,0

plot for [i=1:3] myTitles=myTitles.sprintf(" Data%d",i) '+' u 1:(cos(i*0.1*$1)) w l lw 2 lc i, \
     for [i=4:6] myTitles=myTitles.sprintf(" Data%d",i) '+' u 1:(cos(i*0.1*$1)) w l lw 2 lc i, \
     for [i=1:words(myTitles)] c=((i-1)%M*N+1 + (i-1)/M) '+' u 1:(NaN) w l lw 2 lc c ti word(myTitles,c)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]